# How can I unzip files in Linux when other files are present

Tags: linux, unzip

I have files such as these

```
a1.tif
a2.tif
a1.zip
sa.zip
ff.zip
wqqq.zip
```

1. I want to unzip **only** the zip files and ignore the .tif files
2. Also ignore those .zip files that have already been decompressed.

I am getting this

```
 unzip /*zip
unzip:  cannot find or open /*zip, /*zip.zip or /*zip.ZIP.
```

Comment: `unzip *.zip` or `unzip ./*.zip`

Comment: it shows as filename not matched....: caution: filename not matched:

Comment: caution: filename not matched:  ./no85pr50.zip

Comment: Note: If I do an individual file: unzip ff.zip, it works fine...

Comment: Updated my answer, if there is more than one match it will result in the error you are getting, use `find` to pass each match to `unzip` using the `-exec` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for anything in the root directory that ends with "zip". Use `*.zip` for any file in the current directory ending in ".zip", or more explicitly use `./*.zip`, `./` being the current directory.

That said, if you have more than one match it will pass all of them to the `unzip` command with the first being interpreted as the archive file and the remaining matches as files to extract from the archive. Avoid this by using find to pass each match to `unzip`.

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
```

Comment: It keeps asking me for permission and type 'n' everytime. How can I force it to skip for all files that are already avilable:  [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename

Comment: Maybe this one?  yes n| find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;

Comment: You can see the options for `unzip` using `unzip --help` - the option you want is probably `-n  never overwrite existing files`, so the command would be `find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip -n {} \;`